# Thread Safety in Concurrent Queue C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a `MessagesManager` thread to which different threads may send messages and then this  `MessagesManager` thread is responsible to publish these messages inside `SendMessageToTcpIP()` (start point of `MessagesManager` thread ).

```
class MessagesManager : IMessageNotifier
{
    //private
    private readonly AutoResetEvent _waitTillMessageQueueEmptyARE = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    private ConcurrentQueue<string> MessagesQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>(); 

    public void PublishMessage(string Message)
    {
        MessagesQueue.Enqueue(Message);
        _waitTillMessageQueueEmptyARE.Set();
    }

    public void SendMessageToTcpIP()
    {
        //keep waiting till a new message comes
        while (MessagesQueue.Count() == 0)
        {
            _waitTillMessageQueueEmptyARE.WaitOne();
        }

        //Copy the Concurrent Queue into a local queue - keep dequeuing the item once it is inserts into the local Queue
        Queue<string> localMessagesQueue = new Queue<string>();

        while (!MessagesQueue.IsEmpty)
        {
            string message;
            bool isRemoved = MessagesQueue.TryDequeue(out message);
            if (isRemoved)
                localMessagesQueue.Enqueue(message);
        }

        //Use the Local Queue for further processing
        while (localMessagesQueue.Count() != 0)
        {
            TcpIpMessageSenderClient.ConnectAndSendMessage(localMessagesQueue.Dequeue().PadRight(80, ' '));
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }
    }
}
```

The different threads (3-4) send their message by calling the `PublishMessage(string Message)` (using same object to MessageManager). Once the message comes, I push that message into a ***concurrent queue*** and notifies the  `SendMessageToTcpIP()` by setting `_waitTillMessageQueueEmptyARE.Set();`. **Inside `SendMessageToTcpIP()`, I am copying the message from the concurrent queue inside a local queue and then publish one by one.**

**QUESTIONS:** Is it thread safe to do enqueuing and dequeuing in this way? Could there be some strange effects due to it?

Comment: Why are you checking for counts or using an AutoResetEvent? Why the local queue? The ConcurrentQueue is thred-safe and doesn't need any of that code. If you wanted to iterate over the existing messages you can use `GetConsumingEnumerable()`. That code can only *introduce* thread-safety problems

Comment: Because your messages (of type `string`) are immutable, this should be safe. If, however, your messages were mutable then even though the queue itself is threadsafe, your usage wouldn't necessarily be threadsafe. For example, if some other thread mutated a message while a different thread was using it.

Comment: I am using `AutoResetEvent` because the `MessagesManager` thread is calling `SendMessageToTcpIP()` and it should remain into waiting state until a new message comes.

Comment: And how do you restart SendMessageToTcpIP? It seems it will run just once (no global while loop).

Comment: @skm which it will, even if you don't use that. Dequeueing a message is a blocking operation. A simple `public void SendMessageToTcpIP(){ foreach(var message in MessageQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable(){TcpIpMessageSenderClient.ConnectAndSendMessage(message.PadRight(80, ' ');}}` would be enough

Comment: @Evk: `Main()` starts the `MessageManager` thread and from there `SendMessageToTcpIP()` is getting called in a while loop. So, once its finish its task, it will be recalled and enter into the waiting state until a new message comes.

Comment: Please include an example of how this class is used.

Comment: Well it _seems_ for me it's thread-safe, however if I were you - I will repalce this whole thing with `BlockingCollection` and `GetConsumingEnumerable`. Will be much shorter and readable.

Comment: @skm you have introduced needless complexity with this code. The entire `SendMessageToTcpIP` method could be a one-liner.  You could improve it and *avoid* wasting a thread by sleeping if you used, eg an `ActionBlock<T>` from the TPL Dataflow library. If you pad the message before enquing it, the block can be defined with a simple `var block=new ActionBlock<string>(TcpIpMessageSenderClient.ConnectAndSendMessage);`. After that, posting messages to the block will execute the processing action in a single task (DOP=1 by default) without blocking

Comment: @Evk: There is a wait of 2 seconds after `TcpIpMessageSenderClie‌​nt.ConnectAndSendMes‌​sage(message.PadRigh‌​t(80, ' ');`. Will the conncurrent queue remain blocked during this period?? The other threads can't push new messages during this time?

Comment: @skm why do you need that wait? Is this an actual requirement, or a polling interval? Besides, it's *reading* that blocks, not posting. Whatever it is, nothing prevents you from blocking inside your loop, although an `await Task.Delay(2000);` would avoid wasting a thread

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I need that wait because the messages are getting published on to a HMI listener and therefore an user need sufficient time  to read the message before the next message comes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While this is probably thread-safe, there are built-in classes in .NET to help with "many publishers one consumer" pattern, like `BlockingCollection`. You can rewrite your class like this:

```
class MessagesManager : IDisposable {
    // note that your ConcurrentQueue is still in play, passed to constructor
    private readonly BlockingCollection<string> MessagesQueue = new BlockingCollection<string>(new ConcurrentQueue<string>());

    public MessagesManager() {
        // start consumer thread here
        new Thread(SendLoop) {
            IsBackground = true
        }.Start();
    }

    public void PublishMessage(string Message) {
        // no need to notify here, will be done for you
        MessagesQueue.Add(Message);
    }

    private void SendLoop() {
        // this blocks until new items are available
        foreach (var item in MessagesQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable()) {
            // ensure that you handle exceptions here, or whole thing will break on exception
            TcpIpMessageSenderClient.ConnectAndSendMessage(item.PadRight(80, ' '));
            Thread.Sleep(2000); // only if you are sure this is required 
        }
    }

    public void Dispose() {            
        // this will "complete" GetConsumingEnumerable, so your thread will complete
        MessagesQueue.CompleteAdding();
        MessagesQueue.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: will the publishers be able to push there messages to the `MessageQueue` when the `SendLoop()` is executing `Thread.Sleep(2000);` ?

Comment: Yes sure, publishers can always push to your queue.

Answer (score 2):

.NET already provides [ActionBlock< T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194684(v=vs.110).aspx) that allows posting messages to a buffer and processing them asynchronously. By default, only one message is processed at a time.

Your code could be rewritten as:

```
//In an initialization function
ActionBlock<string> _hmiAgent=new ActionBlock<string>(async msg=>{
        TcpIpMessageSenderClient.ConnectAndSendMessage(msg.PadRight(80, ' '));
        await Task.Delay(2000);
);

//In some other thread ...
foreach ( ....)
{
    _hmiAgent.Post(someMessage);
}

// When the application closes

_hmiAgent.Complete();
await _hmiAgent.Completion;
```

ActionBlock offers many benefits - you can specify a limit to the number of items it can accept in a buffer and specify that multiple messages can be processed in parallel. You can also combine multiple blocks in a processing pipeline. In a desktop application, a message can be posted to a pipeline in response to an event, get processed by separate blocks and results posted to a final block that updates the UI.

Padding, for example, could be performed by an intermediary [TransformBlock< TIn,TOut>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194782(v=vs.110).aspx). This transformation is trivial and the cost of using the block is greater than the method, but that's just an illustration:

```
//In an initialization function
TransformBlock<string> _hmiAgent=new TransformBlock<string,string>(
    msg=>msg.PadRight(80, ' '));

ActionBlock<string> _tcpBlock=new ActionBlock<string>(async msg=>{
        TcpIpMessageSenderClient.ConnectAndSendMessage());
        await Task.Delay(2000);
);

var linkOptions=new DataflowLinkOptions{PropagateCompletion = true};
_hmiAgent.LinkTo(_tcpBlock);
```

The posting code doesn't change at all

```
    _hmiAgent.Post(someMessage);
```

When the application terminates, we need to wait for the _tcpBlock to complete:

```
    _hmiAgent.Complete();
    await _tcpBlock.Completion;
```

Visual Studio 2015+ itself uses TPL Dataflow for such scenarios

Bar Arnon provides a better example in [TPL Dataflow Is The Best Library You're Not Using](http://blog.i3arnon.com/2016/05/23/tpl-dataflow/), that shows how both synchronous and asynchronous methods can be used in a block.

Comment: How are the messages sent to `Post(someMessage)` are taken by ActionBlock?

Comment: `Post` is a method of `ActionBlock` and all other blocks

Comment: @skm `TPL Dataflow` provides a two-step message sending protocol for linked block to ensure the delivery.

Answer (score 0):

This is an refactored code snippet of how I would implement this functionality:

```
class MessagesManager {
    private readonly AutoResetEvent messagesAvailableSignal = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<string> messageQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();

    public void PublishMessage(string Message) {
        messageQueue.Enqueue(Message);
        messagesAvailableSignal.Set();
    }

    public void SendMessageToTcpIP() {
        while (true) {
            messagesAvailableSignal.WaitOne();
            while (!messageQueue.IsEmpty) {
                string message;
                if (messageQueue.TryDequeue(out message)) {
                    TcpIpMessageSenderClient.ConnectAndSendMessage(message.PadRight(80, ' '));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Points to note here:

1. This drains the queue completely: if there is at least one message, it will process all of them
2. The 2000ms Thread sleep is removed

Comment: You don't need the AutoResetEvent at all. You could convert both methods to one line each

Comment: I think the signal is necessary: you want the consumer thread to wait until a message has arrived and not loop endlessly wasting CPU cycles.

Comment: It loops because you used `TryDequeue`. If you didn't it would block waiting for a response. In fact, `GetConsumingEnumerable()` already handles the entire looping behaviour

Comment: I meant in the while(true) => you want it to block there if no messages are available

Comment: If you don't want to block waiting (which you do anyway with `WaitOne()`) use an ActionBlock

Comment: Yes, you don't need to block anything. `Dequeue` itself will block until a message arrives. `GetConsumingEnumerable()` will block the loop until a message arrives. You are treating the `ConcurrentQueue` as if it were a plain `Queue`

Comment: TryDequeue will not block => it will return false if there is no element in the queue

Comment: Yes, that is the bug in this answer. Please read my previous comments and check Evk's correct answer. If you used `Dequeue`, you wouldn't have a problem

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, blocking collection is not same as concurrent. Signaling seems logical way to avoid excessive spinning in this case. Switching to blocking collection may or may not be an option or do you insist it's correct in *all cases*? E.g. what if `PublishMessage` is called by excessive number of writers where *blocking* (that's what `BlockingCollection` will do, right?) is undesired?

Comment: @Sinatr I didn't say that it is concurrent, at all. I said that there is no need for the event because there is no spinning. `GetConsumingEnumerable()` doesn't spin, it blocks. Using `TryDequeue` is what introduced spinning in the first place. Evk already posted a correct answer that doesn't spin or need an event

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos probably it uses some sort of internal signaling. The event logic is more flexible: it can wait a given time period and you can do extra timeout logic there if you want; the GetConsumingEnumerable does not provide this => anyway, is pretty much the same thing.

Comment: You are calling `TryDequeue` twice in the same iteration. Was that intentional? Anyway this code is safe only with one reader, because you don't lock access to `IsEmpty`. You could replace the `while` and both dequeues with `while (!messageQueue.TryDequeue(out message)){...}`. That's one thing you don't have to concern yourself with `GetConsumingEnumerable()`

Answer (score 0):

The code **is** thread safe since both `ConcurrentQueue` and `AutoResetEvent` are thread safe. your strings are anyway being read and never being written to, so this code is thread safe.

However, You have to make sure you call `SendMessageToTcpIP` in some sort of a loop.
otherwise , you have a dangerous race condition - some messages may get lost:

```
while (!MessagesQueue.IsEmpty)
        {
            string message;
            bool isRemoved = MessagesQueue.TryDequeue(out message);
            if (isRemoved)
                localMessagesQueue.Enqueue(message);
        }

        //<<--- what happens if another thread enqueues a message here?

        while (localMessagesQueue.Count() != 0)
        {
            TcpIpMessageSenderClient.ConnectAndSendMessage(localMessagesQueue.Dequeue().PadRight(80, ' '));
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }
```

Other than that, `AutoResetEvent` is extremely heavy object. it uses a kernel object to synchronize threads. every call is a system call which may be costly. consider using user mode synchronization object (doesn't .net provides some sort of condition variable?)

Comment: That loop is already provided by `GetConsumingEnumerable()`. Checking for empty or checking the count isn't necessary

Comment: @David: `SendMessageToTcpIP()` is under a while loop from the `Main()`. If a new message comes then, it will be processed during the next iteration (or next call) of  `SendMessageToTcpIP()`.